# Store Datetime field in localtime in Django

Tags: django, django-database, django-timezone

I use Django 3 with postgresql. `USE_TZ` is False and `TIME_ZONE` is 'Asia/Baku'.
`django.utils.timezone.now()` correctly return Baku localtime, but all `DateTimeFields` with `auto_now_add` save datetime in UTC in database. I want to use localtime everywhere in my app.

edit: I use ubuntu server and timezone is set on Baku